How to test if a variable's value matches a glob-pattern's value
I am writing a Bash script that checks for the differences between two git commits, and cross-references this with a list of glob patterns to see if anything matching those glob patterns has changed.
I'm running up against the limitation that globs are only matched if the glob is defined literally, and not if it is read from a variable.
Here is what I have so far:
function files_changed() {
  local latter_commit=$1
  local former_commit=$2
  local files=("${@:3}")


  for file in $(git diff --name-only "$former_commit" "$latter_commit"); do
    echo "Checking file $file"
        for pattern in "${files[@]}"; do
            if [[ "$file" == $pattern ]]; then
                echo "File $file changed, matched by pattern $pattern"
                return 0
            else
        echo "File $file did not match pattern $pattern"
      fi
        done
    done

    echo "No files changed"
    return 1
}

But this does not work:
array=("migrations/*.up.sql")
files_changed HEAD HEAD~1 ${array[@]}

Output:
Checking file migrations/20240000000001_migration.up.sql
File migrations/20240000000001_migration.up.sql did not match pattern migrations/*.up.sql

If I compare the strings literally I do see the behaviour I want:
> if [[ "migrations/20240000000001_migration.up.sql" == migrations/*.up.sql ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No Match"; fi 
Match

But not if I assign them to variables:
> X=migrations/20240000000001_migration.up.sql; Y=migrations/*.up.sql; if [[ "$X" == $Y ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No Match"; fi
No Match

The workarounds I can find online all hinge on expanding the glob pattern, but that doesn't fit my use case since the file that would match the changelist may not exist in my current filesystem.
How can I make this comparison evaluate correctly?

It works for me. What version of bash is this?

How about case $X in $Y) echo match; esac ? Are you sure you are using Bash in your shell? Also I'm getting $ X=migrations/20240000000001_migration.up.sql; Y=migrations/*.up.sql; if [[ "$X" == $Y ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No Match"; fi Match.

Yah, the case works too but OP's "But not if I assign them to variables" test also works as it should for me, there's something screwy going on here, truly ancient bash version or some weird character encoding issue is my guess.

You may also want to eliminate your loops completely and simply write files to a temp file (e.g. printf "%s\n" ${@:3}" > /tmp/somename) and then simply use if grep -f /tmp/somename < <(git diff --name-only "$former_commit" "$latter_commit"); then ... else ... fi Let grep -f do all the work for you. Note, it will return a list of the files that have changed, so you can capture and loop over those if needed.

Plus, side note to OP, $array is exactly equivalent to ${array[0]}, if you want to pass an entire array as function/command args either use a nameref or pass all the elements with ${array[@]}.

Did you mean to write files_changed HEAD HEAD~1 "${array[@]}"?  It should make no difference for a one-element array, but it will make a tremendous difference with two or more array elements.

@JohnBollinger I took, e.g. $former_commit to be the actual commit number (hex string). So further explanation there is needed.

git diff supports filtering by paths, including with globs: try git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD -- "migrations/*.up.sql". Am I missing something ?

As @LeGEC pointed out git diff allows filtering by globs:
function files_changed() {
    local latter_commit=$1
    local former_commit=$2
    local -a patterns=$3

    for file in $(git diff --name-only "$former_commit" "$latter_commit" -- "${patterns[@]}"); do
        echo "File $file changed, matched by patterns ${patterns[*]}"
    return 0
    done

    echo "No files changed"
    return 1
}

As for the strange behaviour I was seeing, it’s just because I was copying from a file that had a bash shebang into a shell that was running zsh.
